# Static files in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom, node-canvas

In my code that's being tested I'm creating an image like:

```
const image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", () => {});
image.addEventListener("error", () => {});
image.src = "hello.png"
```

When I run in the browser I have webpack copy that image to the dist directory and it works fine. In jest however I get the error `Error: Could not load img: "http://localhost/hello.png"`.

Any guidance on how to "serve" a static image like this in Jest? Where should the image be located in relation to my test file?

(note I've added `testEnvironmentOptions: { resources: 'usable' }` in the jest config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: set the [testURL](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testurl-string) to a local port and then serve the files with [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) / express or something else similar on that port.